# Restructure data into row by week based on date range

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table like this:

```
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE
AA1 2021-01-01  2021-01-27
AA2 2021-01-13  2021-02-09
```

I need to query it to get a list of all Mondays with in the time frame (START_DATE - END_DATE) for each ID . I need to outcome to look like this:

```
ID MONDAY
AA1 2021-01-04
AA1 2021-01-11
AA1 2021-01-18
AA1 2021-01-25
AA2 2021-01-18
AA2 2021-01-25
AA2 2021-02-01
AA2 2021-02-08
```

I am using DB2. I appologize for the weird title but I was not sure how to explain this issue.

Comment: db2 luw ?  What version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BASE CTE here represents your source table.

```
WITH BASE (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) AS 
  ( VALUES ('AA1', DATE('2021-01-01'), DATE('2021-01-27')) , 
           ('AA2', DATE('2021-01-13'), DATE('2021-02-09')) 
  ) , 
  
MONDAYS (MONDAY_DATE) AS 
 (  SELECT ( MIN(START_DATE) + ( 9 - DAYOFWEEK(MIN(START_DATE)) )  DAYS) FROM BASE  
   UNION ALL
    SELECT MONDAY_DATE +  7 DAYS FROM MONDAYS 
      WHERE MONDAY_DATE < ( SELECT MAX(END_DATE) FROM BASE)     
 )

SELECT ID, MONDAY_DATE FROM BASE, MONDAYS 
  WHERE MONDAY_DATE BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE
;
```

produces your desired outcome,  all mondays within the ranges of start/end dates.

```
 ID  MONDAY_DATE
 --- -----------
 AA1 2021-01-04
 AA1 2021-01-11
 AA1 2021-01-18
 AA1 2021-01-25
 AA2 2021-01-18
 AA2 2021-01-25
 AA2 2021-02-01
 AA2 2021-02-08
```

As you already have a base table,  your query should start like :

```
WITH MONDAYS AS (...
```

Comment: you sir, are some kind of a genius. Thank you!